# Jasmine chaining tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, integration-testing

I am using Jasmine to test my project. I use it for integration testing, not for unit testing.

```
describe("admin", function () {

    var testUser =  {
        name: 'test',
        pass: 'pass'
    };

    it("should be able to create a new user", function(done) {
        needle.post(server + "addUser.php", testUser, function (err, res) {
            expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
            done();
        });  
    });

    it("should be able to delete the user", function(done) {
        needle.post(server + "deletedUser.php", testUser, function (err, res) {
            expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
            done();
        });  
    });


});
```

How can I make sure the delete test runs after the add test?

Comment: Maybe this is silly but why not just have a little helper method that creates a user instance and run that in your delete test? My experience with test suites is no guaranteed order but googling around hasn't said whether or not jasmine does this or not.

Comment: I think jasmine supports this, but I do not know exactly how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the answer may be this simple: Jasmine runs tests in the order of their appearance, even the async ones.

To test this I tried with:

```
it("A", function (done) {
    console.log("A");
    setTimeout(done, 4000); 
});

it("B", function (done) {
    console.log("B");
    setTimeout(done, 20);
});

it("C", function () { 
    console.log("C");
});
```

And the output was `ABC`, test `B` doesn't start before `done` from test `A` is called.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who might stumble across this: using a slightly larger test set shows  that order is not guaranteed (since jasmine 2.3.0):

```
it('a', function (done) { console.log('a'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('b', function (done) { console.log('b'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('c', function (done) { console.log('c'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('d', function (done) { console.log('d'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('e', function (done) { console.log('e'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('f', function (done) { console.log('f'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('g', function (done) { console.log('g'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('h', function (done) { console.log('h'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('i', function (done) { console.log('i'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('j', function (done) { console.log('j'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('k', function (done) { console.log('k'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('l', function (done) { console.log('l'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('m', function (done) { console.log('m'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('n', function (done) { console.log('n'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('o', function (done) { console.log('o'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('p', function (done) { console.log('p'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('q', function (done) { console.log('q'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('r', function (done) { console.log('r'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('s', function (done) { console.log('s'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('t', function (done) { console.log('t'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('u', function (done) { console.log('u'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('v', function (done) { console.log('v'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('w', function (done) { console.log('w'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('x', function (done) { console.log('x'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('y', function (done) { console.log('y'); setTimeout(done, 100); });
it('z', function (done) { console.log('z'); setTimeout(done, 100); });

// 2.1.0: a b c d e f g h i l k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
// 2.2.0: a b c d e f g h i l k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
// 2.3.0: a z c d e f g h i j k l m b o p q r s t u v w x y n
// 2.3.1: a z c d e f g h i j k l m b o p q r s t u v w x y n
```

Follow along [here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/850) for updates (if any).

UPDATE: it was a bug and was fixed with v2.3.4. All tests should be ordered now.